# Why is Python Watchdog emitting multiple (seemingly incorrect) events on file change?

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I am trying to build the ability to start a simple server to preview a site while using [Watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/index.html) to watch the source files for changes. When changes are detected, I want to stop the server, build the site, then restart the server. This is what I have right now which works pretty well, except for the stop-build-start bit:

```
# Dict containing config
config = {
    [...]
    "source_dir": "/path/to/source"
    "build_dir": "/path/to/build"
    [...]
}


# Run a local dev server
def create_server():
    os.chdir(config["build_dir"])
    httpd = HTTPServer(("", 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()


def dev():
    class DevServer(FileSystemEventHandler):
        p = None

        def start_server(self):
            if self.p:
                self.stop_server()
            build()
            print("Starting server...")
            self.p = Process(target=create_server)
            self.p.start()

        def stop_server(self):
            if self.p:
                print("Stopping server...")
                self.p.terminate()

        def on_any_event(self, event):
            if event.is_directory:
                return None
            else:
                self.stop_server()
                build()
                self.start_server()

    devserver = DevServer()
    devserver.start_server()

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(devserver, config["source_dir"], recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Whenever I make a change to an existing source file, the stop-build-start runs four times. I changed the the `on_any_event` function to just print the events to try and get a sense of why and this is what I got:

```
<FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='/path/to/source/file.type', is_directory=False>
<DirModifiedEvent: event_type=modified, src_path='/path/to/source', is_directory=True>
<FileDeletedEvent: event_type=deleted, src_path='/path/to/source/file.type', is_directory=False>
<DirModifiedEvent: event_type=modified, src_path='/path/to/source', is_directory=True>
```

*(I modified the paths above for brevity, but they are the actual paths when running the code.)*

How would I make this work as expected?

I'd also like to understand why saving a single existing file is emitting four events and why the two file events are for creation and deletion of a file, when what I did was save (modify) a file?

Comment: *How* are you making a chance to the source file? Some editors work by editing a temporary file, and then deleting the target and re-creating it when you save changes. This results in set of operations to what you've described.

Comment: @larsks That might well be it. I'm mostly editing in Panic's Nova, but tried SubEthaEdit, IA Writer and TextEdit and got more-or-less the same result (IA Writer seems to do some insane stuff with temp files, but essentially similar). Editing one of the watched files in nano delivers the expected result, however.

The order of events seems a little odd -- create before delete -- but know that I know what's happening, I can just test for `create` or `modify` events and act on those.

The comment was super helpful, thank you!

Comment: The solution to this sort of situation is to *not* respond to every event. E.g., only trigger your action *n* milliseconds after the last event has been received (resetting the timer if a new events comes in).